# Qt: Drawing on QQuickView

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qgraphicsitem

I searched for many hours, but did not find a good answer - can I drawing on QQuickView with C++? On QGraphicsScene I can add an ellipse or a rectangle (QGraphicsEllipseItem, ...), but how can I do it on QQuickView without QML?
Or could I create a custom C++ object dynamically and add it to QML? Unfortunately the Qt object only seems to be existing in QML (Qt.createQmlObject()).

Comment: Are you asking about this tutorial? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquick/scenegraph-customgeometry.html

Comment: No, I'm sorry. Well, I would like to add this bezier curve for example, dynamically to qquickview without writing BezierCurve{} node in a qml file.

Comment: Have you tried drawing on Canvas?

Comment: Yes, you can: just a) create the object (simplest way is to use a QQuickPaintedItem) b) parent it to an existing scene c) set it up so that it has proper geometry, line widths, etc -- all in C++.

Comment: @mlvjir - that's a very good, simple idea. Then I should set background color of QQuickPaintedItem to transparent. So I can drawing on both areas simultaneously.. - Thank you!